# Plotly Dash - Restyle multiple graphs with buttons

Tags: button, plotly, plotly-dash

By following the [tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/#relayout-button), I know how to restyle my graph with buttons. But is it possible I can restyle multiple graphs at the same time?

What I’m trying to do is displaying different world indices in different data length. Let’s say there are 5 buttons [1 month], [6 months], [1 year], [5 years] and [10 years]. And I want different graphs display specific data length according to which button has been clicked on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with plotly dash, **yes**.

You would create a dropdown menu (or radio items) – since only one button can be selected at a time (I presume). On change of selection, you would then pass the reformatting command to a list of graph objects. It's that simple.

See more here: https://dash.plot.ly/interactive-graphing

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That radioitem works for me. But I'm wondering that can I achieve this with buttons? or I can decorate radioitem into button?

Comment: You absolutely can format it as a button. @王仁宏 – why don't you post it as a new Q and I'll answer it.

Comment: Also, if you found this answer helpful, I would appreciate if you upvoted or accepted it @王仁宏